# Are there countries where the legislative body is not allowed to propose laws that touch upon unrelated subjects?

Tags: policy, legislation

As a recent example, the recent $2.3 trillion stimulus bill contained not just provisions related to supporting the American people, but also [a requirement to produce a report on UFOs](https://www.newsweek.com/ufo-report-government-agencies-180-days-1557945):

> Federal agencies have been asked to publish a report on unidentified
> flying objects (UFOs) in less than 180 days, thanks to an act included
> in the $2.3 trillion stimulus and government spending bill signed by
> President Donald Trump on Sunday.
>
> A report by the Select Committee on Intelligence attached to the The
> Intelligence Authorization Act for 2021 states that the Director of
> National Intelligence, the Secretary of Defense and the heads of other
> relevant agencies submit a report to the congressional intelligence
> and armed services committees on "unidentified aerial phenomena (also
> known as "anomalous aerial vehicles''), including observed airborne
> objects that have not been identified." They are asked to do this 180
> days after the act is enacted.

Are there countries where a proposed law may only focus on one single topic?

Comment: Whomever gets to decide what is "on topic" would have great power to shape and block legislature. Best to not vest that in one person, or party, or committee. Perhaps the whole chamber should vote on it. :)

Comment: I wonder if the Newsweek reporting is even correct on that. Because the The Intelligence Authorization Act for 2021 seems to be a different bill.

Comment: However, what you describe here is generally valid and known as "lighting up the Christmas tree" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_tree_bill

Comment: This was **not** a $2.3 trillion stimulus bill. It was instead a $1.4 trillion omnibus spending bill that the Congress had worked on for many months, plus a $900 billion stimulus addendum added at the last moment. The omnibus spending bill in turn comprises twelve separate bills that Congress decided to package together as one single bill. Like it or not, some small but arguably objectionable things (and this silly UFO investigation is a small thing) inevitably get inserted into these spending bills. "It is what it is."

Comment: @Fizz The Intelligence Authorization Act of 2021 is Division W of the 2021 Consolidated Appropriations Act (aka the omnibus spending bill).

Comment: Coronavirus relief is a big deal so it's understandable that commentary would focus on that but it resulted in a frequent mischaracterization of the bill. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolidated_Appropriations_Act,_2021) is not a “stimulus bill” but an omnibus spending bill that was required for the government to continue to function and by nature covers many different topics. If you are looking for a bill with a clear focus and a discussion of riders in general, this is one of the worse examples you could find.

Comment: @DavidHammen: it is and it isn't. There's indeed a division W with that title and a few short provisions, but there's also the much longer H. R. 7856 aka "Intelligence Authorization Act for Fiscal Year 2021"
 https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/7856/text It looks like the Senate decided that was missing an UFO report, so they've added that W section to the appropriations.

Comment: @DavidHammen Why is that "inevitable"?  That makes it sounds like some sort of force of nature, but what if we lived in a world where politicians behaved like honest professional adults (ha ha)?

Comment: I would go so far to say that especially the extent to which a law in the US can govern anything from the length of grass on public grounds to the budget for military spending and the tax benefit for oil companies, all within a single bill that originally was meant to raise veteran pensions is quite unique to the USA. No other country I know of has that kind of approach to legislation.

Comment: @gerrit This particular item was inevitable because (1) The President does not have a line item veto. A line item veto was passed in 1996 but found unconstitutional in 1998. The lack of a line item veto lets small smelly things pass through the budgeting process. (2) UFOlogists exist in both houses and on both sides of the aisle. Harry Reid, the former Senate Majority Leader, was a famous example. (3) Belief that UFOs are real, or at least might be real, waxes during stressful times and wanes when everything's cool. 2020 was rather stressful.

Answer (score 55):

Depending on how one defines "one single topic", the rule applies in the UK.

Erskine May - the bible of parliamentary procedure in the UK - has this to say on [the scope of a bill](https://erskinemay.parliament.uk/section/5313/the%20scope%20of%20a%20bill/):

> Any amendment (or new clause or new schedule) proposed to a bill must be within its scope. The scope of a bill represents the reasonable limits of its collective purposes, as defined by its existing clauses and schedules. In particular cases, difficult questions of judgment may arise. The scope of a bill, particularly of a bill with several purposes, may be wider than its long title, although the long title may help to determine the scope.

In other words, a bill's [long title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_and_long_titles) is intended to summarise the scope of the bill. Any amendment which is outside that scope is likely to be [ruled out of order](https://erskinemay.parliament.uk/section/5337/inadmissible-amendments/).

Admittedly, that's not quite the same as saying that a bill must only contain matters [pertaining to a single subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-subject_rule); but that is the effect, and so [omnibus bills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnibus_bill) are unknown in the UK (at least nowadays).

Note that this does make [riders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rider_(legislation)) ("an additional provision added to a bill [...], having little connection with the subject matter of the bill.") all but impossible; and amendments relating to money can only be made by the government.

It's less clear what happens if any content in the original bill (before any amendments are made) fails to match the long title. It may be that amendments are made either to remove the offending clauses, or to amend the long title to reflect the actual contents of the bill.

Comment: +1 but budgets are generally not subject to this. One doesn't pass separate laws to fund the armed forces vs the NHS, as far as I know. In fact looking at an actual UK budged, I'm sure of that https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/752202/Budget_2018_red_web.pdf

Comment: @Fizz: that is true. In a typical year, there is just one Act which covers any changes and renewals of taxes ([Finance Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finance_Act)). There are also multiple Acts per year which authorise the spending (well, appropriation and allocation) of money. I guess the single subject in these two cases are "raising money" and "spending money"!

Comment: I believe the title had to match the contents of the bill.  The bill to enable Brexit was originality to be submitted as "The Great Repeal Bill",  but this was considered (by the speaker and clerks of the House) to be insufficiently descriptive of the contents,  so if was actually submitted as "European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018".

Comment: @Fizz a complementary piece of parliamentary procedure, which prevents riders being added to budgets, is that unlike in the US, if a budget isn't passed, this is treated as a vote of no confidence, which automatically triggers a general election, where all seats are up for grabs. I feel like if congress knew that it was *their* jobs that would be lost if they blocked an appropriations bill, government shutdowns and riders on budgets in the US would not be a thing.

Comment: @James_pic - true, though since the passing of the Fixed Term Parliaments Act, this is no longer automatic. However, that Act is likely to be reviewed this year, so things could conceivably go back to how they were.

Comment: @PhillS That's the "short title" of a bill. The thing that matters is the "long title".

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff I think probably what is more important, is that in Britain, political parties - and especially party whips - have a bigger part to play than is the case in the US. The US riders to bills, are the result of "pork-barrel" politics where individual members (eg someone interested in UFOs) can, when votes are being canvassed, find they are powerful enough to insist upon a rider. Any MP in Britain trying that would first have to answer to his whip. Parties are more powerful in the UK than in the US.But +1 for the answer.

Comment: @PhillS The "long title" of that Act is "An Act to Repeal the European Communities Act 1972 and make other provision in connection with the withdrawal of the United Kingdom from the EU." The short title doesn't strictly need to be _descriptive_, only _distinctive_, as it's used to cite the Act in other legal documents. On the other hand, short titles tend towards boringly to-the-point rather than the catchy titles and acronyms more favoured in the US, so "Great Repeal Act" was a rather pompous suggestion even if it had described the contents.

Answer (score 27):

[Riders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rider_(legislation)) are forbidden in France, where the constitutional court (*conseil constitutionnel*) simply nullifies them whenever it reviews a bill. Rules are stricter now than they used to be and the court is enforcing them more aggressively in [the hope of making them worthless](https://www.conseil-constitutionnel.fr/publications/titre-vii/le-controle-des-cavaliers-legislatifs-entre-continuite-et-innovations). Obviously, any process or measure that prevents unrelated amendments to a bill restricts the freedom and independence of the parliament and this one is no exception.

Comment: " is enforcing them more actively in the hope of making them worthless" => can you expand on that? Google Translate doesn't give a very good picture.

Comment: @JonathanReez: basically the article says that the CC (which actually made up this rule circa 1985) is enforcing it even more strictly since 2006. However looking a graph further in the article, it doesn't look like that's really working...

Comment: @JonathanReez; Then, apparently the French constitution was amended (article 45) in 2008 with respect to riders. It's not clear if that has made any difference... but the new article allows an "indirect link".

Comment: @Fizz If you follow the reasoning of the author, it seems to have an effect. The first chart plots reportedly suggests the CC was less strict around 2013-2015, which was followed by a new peak in unrelated riders in 2014-2017 (second chart). Being more aggressive then brought them back down.

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically, there is a rule regarding this in the Romanian legislation. Article 14 of the Law 24 from 2000 says "an act may include normative regulations regarding other related matter only insofar as they are essential for attaining the desired purpose of this act". However, in practice this rule is often ignored  (sometimes, Emergency Government Ordinances contain changes to various unrelated laws).

Answer (score 4):

Greece's constitutional provisions regarding parliamentary procedure forbid the parliamentary discussion of bills containing unrelated topics. Specifically, [article 74, paragraph 5 of the Greek Constitution](https://www.hellenicparliament.gr/Vouli-ton-Ellinon/To-Politevma/Syntagma/article-76/) ([also available in English](https://www.hellenicparliament.gr/UserFiles/f3c70a23-7696-49db-9148-f24dce6a27c8/001-156%20aggliko.pdf)) stipulates that a) a law  proposal  containing  provisions
not  related  to  its  main  subject  matter  shall  not be introduced  for  debate, and b) no  addition  or  amendment  shall  be  introduced  for  debate  if  it  is  not  related  to  the  main subject  matter  of  the  Bill  or  law  proposal.

In practice these rules are honored in the breach rather than the observance. The Constitution also stipulates that Parliament rules on any disputes related to these rules, and, I guess, this is the loophole used for discussing and passing bills that do not respect them.

Answer (score 4):

What [Accumulation says](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/61366/23493) is not exactly correct (but too long to put this as a mere comment). Many US state laws [nominally](https://lawreview.law.pitt.edu/ojs/index.php/lawreview/article/viewFile/55/55) forbid riders in legislation passed by their regular legislature:

> In 1818, a single subject requirement for bills pertaining to government
> salaries materialized in the Illinois Constitution. [...] By 1959, some version of the rule had been adopted in forty-three states. **The provision in the Nebraska
> Constitution is typical: “No bill shall contain more than one subject, and the
> subject shall be clearly expressed in the title.”**
>
> As this quotation suggests, single subject rules almost universally include
> a title provision. This [latter] requirement has independent historical roots, making
> its inaugural appearance in the Georgia Constitution after the 1795 “Yazoo
> Land Fraud.” Members of the Georgia legislature passed a bill—titled “An
> Act for the Payment of the late State Troops”—that transferred vast tracts of
> public land to private companies. Many politicians profited from the act,
> which was “smuggled through the legislature under an innocent and deceptive
> title.” Thereafter, General James Jackson demanded that each bill contain
> a title that adequately expressed its contents, and a provision to that effect was
> added to the Constitution in 1798. Many other states adopted similar
> provisions.

And as a historical precedent perhaps:

> the Romans in 98 B.C. forbade laws consisting of unrelated provisions.

The paper also discusses the level of enforcement, but that's probably too long to get to here, but I'll throw in this graph, cumulative over all US states:

> [image]

The graph is based on a somewhat crude methodology of counting all invocations of the rule(s) in lawsuits, not even necessarily those where the (state) courts even took them into account in their judgement. And also as a map...

> [image]

Comment: There more recent papers on the US states on that matter https://scholarship.law.columbia.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3593&context=faculty_scholarship but alas I can't find a single comparative one across other countries, to give some sort of overview how widespread this is on the globe, or even in e.g. Europe...

Answer (score 4):

The Czech constitutional court has ruled "wild" [riders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rider_(legislation)) (addendums completely unrelated to orignal purpose of the law) unconstitutional and has nullified some particular cases ([court decision in Czech](http://nalus.usoud.cz/Search/GetText.aspx?sz=Pl-77-06)). The reasoning was that riders make the law unpredictable and hard to understand and make it possible that the rules were not discussed thoroughly and in their full context before they are approved in the leigslative body -  all of which contradicts the spirit (although AFAIK not letter) of the constitution.  So there is AFAIK no explicit law to forbid riders, but you can litigate to get riders nullified and there is precedent for this to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Many states in the U.S. have [a single subject rule](https://ballotpedia.org/Single-subject_rule), however those apply to voter-initiated legislation, not to legislation introduced by the legislature.